# Exception: terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all

Tags: ios, ios5

I am trying to pull a VC xib, by adding the view of controller on window's view. When I execute the program nothing appears (a black screen), and expectation was a button put on view of VC in xib. 
But when I declare that this VC is my Project's main interface (Project Summary), then it throws the exception : terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all and application crashes.

Here is the code for didfinishlaunch (Appdelegate)

```
[self.window addSubview:rootViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Can somebody assist on that.

Thanks

PS: the complete error is given below

2012-02-26 11:50:08.003 PasswordGeneratorTest[1161:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13b9052 0x154ad0a 0x13b8f11 0x9b0032 0x921f7b 0x921eeb 0x93cd60 0x22f91a 0x13bae1a 0x1324821 0x22e46e 0x230010 0x1014a 0x10461 0xf7c0 0x1e743 0x1f1f8 0x12aa9 0x12a3fa9 0x138d1c5 0x12f2022 0x12f090a 0x12efdb4 0x12efccb 0xf2a7 0x10a9b 0x1d42 0x1cb5)
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
Single stepping until exit from function __pthread_kill, 
which has no line number information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your stack trace code or the message the debugger is giving you, but there's ALWAYS 2 reasons why it would crash here:

1. `rootViewController.view` is nil or doesn't have its view outlet set in IB.
2. `self.window` is not set in code or doesn't have its outlet connected in IB.

Check all of your outlets and see if it fixes it.

Comment: thanks..i have checked your first point, but I am not understanding the second one. I am working on Xcode 4.2 and doesn't make any window object in xib & no MainWindow xib. You may see the whole stack trace i have updated my question.

Comment: thanks buddy, problem resolved. I have just initiated rootViewController with nib and removed Main nib = RootViewController from .plist. Can you please tell why removal of Main nib file Key make it possible! When I am including this Key, it's again crashing down.

Comment: no this was just to make you understand that i have assigned this key a value "RootViewController". I didn't use = with it.

Comment: Just don't set a root view controller in the Plist then.  Usually, the primary xib is set in the tab under Project > Summary > Main Interface

Comment: Yes, if you set the initial xib into Main Interface, your Xcode automatically creates Main nib file key also. In this case I am not doing it just because it is the only cause of crashing of application. But why? , if you understand what's happening.